# Activity Monitor suddenly showing all cores in Dock icon

Tags: macos, dock, activity-monitor

After upgrading my MBP from Mavericks to Yosemite, the "CPU History" option of the Activity Monitor only showed one aggregate graph.

After reinstalling Yosemite from scratch, I suddenly have 8 tiny graphs, one for each core, which I find too tiny to be useful. Is there any way to switch the Dock icon of Activity Monitor back to the single graph?

Answer (score 4):

I saw this on a fresh install on 10.10.4. To fix it, close Activity Monitor and then:

```
defaults write com.apple.activitymonitor IconType -int 4
```

Comment: This fix still works in Sierra 10.12.5. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't work on 10.13.6! :(

Comment: It works in Mojave / 10.14, but the command should be: `defaults write com.apple.activitymonitor IconType 4` (without the `-int`)

Comment: Does not work for me.  On a 10.14.3 machine where it does not show all cores (but a composite graph, like I want), the value of the `IconType` is 6.  Setting it to that on another machine with 10.14.3 does not make it stop displaying all the cores.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS Mojave

This command show all the processors
    
`defaults write com.apple.activitymonitor IconType 5`

This command show only one composite graph
    
`defaults write com.apple.activitymonitor IconType 4`


The "all processor graph" doesn't work on MacBook and MBPro

The "composite graph" doesn't work on the old Pro desktops